# Loop through each element and store as variable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a system generated table that houses links in each of it's row elements. Each of these links has a unique 4 digit value at the end of the link.

The goal is to iterate through each of these table elements, grab the link it holds and then slice that link down to just the final 4 characters.

I've got this running right now:

**HTML**

```
<td class="lc_Cell">
    <p>
        <a href="thelink">Link #1</a>
    </p>
</td>
<td class="lc_Cell">
    <p>
        <a href="thelink">Link #2</a>
    </p>
</td>
<td class="lc_Cell">
    <p>
        <a href="thelink">Link #3</a>
    </p>
</td>
<td class="lc_Cell">
    <p>
        <a href="thelink">Link #4</a>
    </p>
</td>
```

**Jquery**

```
var TRLink = $(".lc_Cell > p > a").attr("href");   //The original URL the program spits out
var TR_ID = TRLink.slice(-4);   // Storing just the 4 digits I need
var NewLink = $(".lc_Cell > p > a").attr("href","mynewlinktosendsomeoneto"+ TR_ID); 
// my new link that utilizes the 4 characters from the original
```

This kind of works... the initial variable stores the link of the first instance it finds (in my actual code there are 3 others). When I create the NewLink variable it then overwrites ALL occurrences.

In a perfect world I'd iterate through and store the original links, do my slice and then iterate through and re-build a new link for each.

I came across the "each.()" command in jQuery but didn't have much luck getting a solution to work on my own.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you could use `map()` to build an array of the last four characters of the `href` attributes of all the relevant `a` elements:

```js
var ids = $('.lc_Cell a').map(function() {
  return this.href.slice(-4);
}).get();

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="lc_Cell">
      <p>
        <a href="thelink1234">Link #1</a>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td class="lc_Cell">
      <p>
        <a href="thelink2345">Link #2</a>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td class="lc_Cell">
      <p>
        <a href="thelink3456">Link #3</a>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td class="lc_Cell">
      <p>
        <a href="thelink4567">Link #4</a>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That being said, given your aim to update the `href` attributes on the `a` elements it makes more sense in this case to provide a function to `attr()` which you can use to return a new value based on their current one. Something like this:

```
$('.lc_Cell a').attr('href', function(i, href) {
  var id = href.slice(-4); 
  return 'mynewlinktosendsomeoneto' + id; 
});
```

Comment: HUGE help! Thanks a lot Rory that gives me pretty much all I need to get this done.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note that I just added an edit regarding an even easier way to update all the `href` values in a single pass if you'd prefer that instead.

Comment: The edit is like magic! You're a god-send on this one. 
So just so I fully understand and am not just copy/pasting and moving along... Since I have multiple occurrences of the table cell this function essentially acts as a loop because it runs on each of those occurrences and then updates the link href before moving on to the next one?

Comment: That's it exactly. The function inside `attr()` will be run on every instance of the `.lc_Cell a` element.